# How to make the blur text in the text box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make the blur text in the text box like on the Username row.

[image]

Comment: Just change the foreground color of the text box to *lightgray* or *"#a0a0a0"*.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips. We don't even know if you are talking about a `tkinter.Entry` or a `ttk.Entry`. If this is the former, start by reading the documentation, e.g. https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AdleyLe. Do you mean gray out?

Comment: @j_4321 i can't post all my code because of the review question

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yeah  , it'll disappear when i type on it

Comment: @acw1668 and how to make it disappear when i type in the textbox ?